# Doxygen exclude getter and setter

Tags: java, doxygen, getter

is it possible to configure Doxygen to exclude my getter and setter? We're using beans Extensivly, and for the internal documentation there is really no need to have the getter and setter visible every time. However, i'd like to keep

```
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
```

as it's good to see what still needs documentation.
I thought that I could achive this with EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS, but till now I didn't succeed. Here's my try:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =  */*::get*
```

I also tried `*::get*`, `*/*::get*` etc, but none of these seemed to work. Any help is appriciated!

Comment: Did you try something like `*.get*`? I mean use dot instead of double colons?

Comment: tried that, didn't help either :(

Comment: Interesting to know. Why javadoc is not enough?

Comment: because javadoc doesn't work on other languages - and the doxygen output is much more versatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [\cond](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond) command ?

You will have to manually "tag" all of your files, but you will gain in granularity : if you create some kind of getter or setter that you want in the documentation, it will be possible.